# Check if mask data is available in String

Tags: javascript, java, performance, groovy, jmeter

I am trying whether string contains mask data in given String.
String Response = 0H1400Y0000X0 1'00000000   110|11001 ;
I need to validate Response.contains(maskdata);
Can you someone help on this.
I am using JMeter to validate this process.

Note : mask data means my sensitive information like XXXX021

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. Also please take some time to format your code a bit - right now it's not clear, what is what.

Comment: I'm going to assume you mean Java and not javascript. If so, I would remove javascript from the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), example configuration would be something like:

[image]

If you're still looking for a Groovy based solution:

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('XXXX021')) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('The mask wasn not found in the response')
   }
   ```

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)